# jquery ajax request continues to run after error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

This is my code

```
early_face_detect=$.ajax({
type: "POST",
    url: "earlydetect.py",
    timeout: 15000,
    success: function(respond) { 
    var s=grab_early_details(respond);
},
error: function(xmlhttprequest, textstatus, message) {
    alert('close');
    }
});
```

After error occurs it enters the 'error' block but in the background 'earlydetect.py' continues to run. Is there any way to kill its execution once error occurs?

here is my earlydetect.py code snippet

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    while bool:
        # Grab a single frame of video
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()

        # Resize frame of video to 1/4 size for faster face recognition processing
        small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)

        # Only process every other frame of video to save time
        if process_this_frame:
            # Find all the faces and face encodings in the current frame of video
            face_locations = face_recognition_api.face_locations(small_frame)
            face_encodings = face_recognition_api.face_encodings(small_frame, face_locations)

            face_names = []
            predictions = []
            if len(face_encodings) > 0:
                closest_distances = clf.kneighbors(face_encodings, n_neighbors=1)

                is_recognized = [closest_distances[0][i][0] <= 0.5 for i in range(len(face_locations))]

                # predict classes and cull classifications that are not with high confidence
                predictions = [(le.inverse_transform(int(pred)).title(), loc) if rec else ("Unknown", loc) for pred, loc, rec in
                               zip(clf.predict(face_encodings), face_locations, is_recognized)]

            # # Predict the unknown faces in the video frame
            # for face_encoding in face_encodings:
            #     face_encoding = face_encoding.reshape(1, -1)
            #
            #     # predictions = clf.predict(face_encoding).ravel()
            #     # person = le.inverse_transform(int(predictions[0]))
            #
            #     predictions = clf.predict_proba(face_encoding).ravel()
            #     maxI = np.argmax(predictions)
            #     person = le.inverse_transform(maxI)
            #     confidence = predictions[maxI]
            #     print(person, confidence)
            #     if confidence < 0.7:
            #         person = 'Unknown'
            #
            #     face_names.append(person.title())

        process_this_frame = not process_this_frame


        # Display the results
        for name, (top, right, bottom, left) in predictions:
            # Scale back up face locations since the frame we detected in was scaled to 1/4 size
            top *= 4
            right *= 4
            bottom *= 4
            left *= 4

            # Draw a box around the face
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

            # Draw a label with a name below the face
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
            cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)
            if name!="Unknown":
                bool = False
                name_face = name
        # Display the resulting image
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

        # Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    # Release handle to the webcam
    video_capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It helps in detecting face if found it prints its name which is receivd back to ajax request else ajax timeout is set which results in error. But even after timeout earlydetect.py keeps on executing

Comment: share you `python` snippet which triggers this request

Comment: there is a chance of earlydetect.py is getting invoked first and the error is actually throwing from the python script.

Comment: i have added my earlydetect.py code snippet

Comment: no error is thrown due to timeout @NishadKAhamed

Answer (score 0):

You must abort after receiving an error

```
early_face_detect=$.ajax({
type: "POST",
    url: "earlydetect.py",
    timeout: 15000,
    success: function(respond) { 
    var s=grab_early_details(respond);
},
error: function(xmlhttprequest, textstatus, message) {
    alert('close');
    // Abort xmlhttprequest
    xmlhttprequest.abort();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I already tried aborting it, earlydetect.py continues to run in background

Comment: I misunderstand the problem. I would also recommend running time in the earlydetect.py file, such as timeout found in Ajax, and defining timeout in non-stop transaction.
detail : https://dreamix.eu/blog/webothers/timeout-function-in-python-3